# Switch/case usage for selected value in selectbox

Tags: javascript, html

I have a selectbox with a couple of options in it. When an option is selected, the Javascript code gets the value of the selected option and has to change the font of a text accordingly.

I figured I would use the Switch-Case statement because I have multiple options, but it doesn't seem to work, nothing changes.

**Javascript**

```
function font() {
    var sf = document.getElementById('box').value;
    var generate = document.getElementById('generate');

    switch (sf) {
        case 'TimesNewRoman':
            generate.style.fontFamily('Times New Roman')
            break;
        case 'Georgia':
            generate.style.fontFamily('Georgia')
            break;
        case 'PalatinoLinotype':
            generate.style.fontFamily('Palatino Linotype')
            break;
        default:
            generate.style.fontFamily('Arial')
    }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<select id="box" onchange="font();">
    <option id="TNR" value="TimesNewRoman">Times New Roman</option>
    <option id="GRG" value="Georgia">Georgia</option>
    <option id="PLT" value="PalatinoLinotype">Palatino Linotype</option>
</select>
<br />
<div id="generate">This is some text</div>
```

**NOTE**

I have more options in the list but I have shorten it for the sake of simplicity.

Am I wrong for using this statement, or am I missing something entirely?

Comment: I think you mean to make an assignment `generate.style.fontFamily = 'Palatino Linotype'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't made an assignment, use `generate.style.fontFamily = "Arial";`